# Suggest me tutorial for Dapps and solidity programming

Tags: solidity, blockchain, tokens, dapps, ico

I am new to learning solidity programming and dpps development. Please share the fine tutorial for both.

Hope get the fine answers...

Comment: Since this is still being references, consider the official solidity documentation, it contains a wealth of examples and explanations and is "official" and "complete": https://solidity.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 2):

[Crypto Zombies](https://cryptozombies.io/) is most interactive and informative tutorial . It takes you step by step to a full functioning dapp. Good luck.

Comment: I second the cryptozombies tutorial. Also check out this video series: [What's solidity](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaWes1eWQ9TbzA695gl_PtA)

Answer (score 2):

I am currently going through [this Udemy Ethereum master class](https://www.udemy.com/ethereum-masterclass/learn/v4/overview) which takes you to ultimately write a **decentralised ERC20 token exchange**.

- **The first videos** cover a lot of **theory** which might sound boring but is quite essential. I found the part on `solidity` vulnerabilities and hacks quite interesting as it triggered an additional dose of web crawling to better understand the security aspects of smart contracts.
- **The second part** of the videos goes into the real **coding action**. The solidity code that you write is not basic and is packed with a lot of concepts very specific to `solidity`. You will also cover the development of the web front end calling your smart contract.

At the end of the day you need to start somewhere.

This course really helped me kick off my journey to DApps development.

Happy learning !

Answer (score 0):

I started with CryptoZombies. Very good to have a basic idea.
After that just like Fabien. I'm taking the Udemy Ethereum master class which what he wrote would be my exact answer. Very good Course. Up Vote for Fabien.
(Not related) Always remember to take notes and read them before going to sleep. This help retain what you learned.